# MenuItem actionView aligns right

Tags: android, android-actionbar

As the title says, I'm setting using `setActionView` on a `MenuItem`, here's the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The issue is that the `ProgressBar` appears aligned to the right. (It should be aligned to the center, same as the `MenuItem` icon. Icons are `32dp`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue today and coudn't find any good QA on SO. Hence I did some research. Here are my findings on the matter:

> Android Menu is implemented in this way:

If you have inflated an **actionView** to have:

- icon (optional)
- title (optional, or to say it can be made optional by setting it as "")
- a custom view

and you don't set icon, set title as "" and set actionView to make the menuItem appear to contain only the custom view which you inflated using setActionView, then:

[image]

> Android forces the custom view's **width** to be **wrap_content** and remaining area gets occupied by icon+title of the menuItem.

We can think of this implementation as:

[image]

[image]

Think of the entire view after margin as **ParentLinearLayout** which is divided into **LinearLayout1** and **LinearLayout2** (depicted in the image above as Layout 1 and Layout 2 respectively)

Now **LinearLayout1** has **width=0dp** and **weight=1**
And **LinearLayout2** has **width=wrap_content**

Hence no matter what we set, currently, we cannot right align the inflated custom view (action view) in menu.

> To be technically accurate, you can right align if you really need this done by checking out the internal implementation code for the navigation menu by Android. But not really worth the effort. Any feature is a tradeoff of time required vs outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, saved me plenty of frustration as to why it wasn't aligning correctly

Answer (score 0):

You should try `android:gravity="center"` in `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Is that RelativeLayout add in to any other view. If so for testing purpose give some color to the RelativeLayout and see how it spacing in the parent view in run time.

Comment: The `ProgressBar` seems to be on the center of the `RelativeLayout`, but the `RelativeLayout` doesn't look like the other action icon's width

Answer (score 0):

Try this `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: Which tag to apply this to?

Comment: Just put it for progressbar